# Django Many-To-One IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, many-to-one

I am new to Python and Django. I created database due to documents. I tested it and there has been error to many-to-one relationship between two models.

It looks weird to me because It works like one to one relationship between those classes but it gives error if I try to add many. There are other classes with same relationship as many-to-one. I created same way and they work just fine. I am using sqlite by the way.

```
class unites (models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    unitename = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class intensivecare_forms (models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    hospitals_id = models.ForeignKey(hospitals, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    formname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    data = models.JSONField()
    unites_id = models.ForeignKey(unites, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It gives this error if I try to add second form into unites.

```
IntegrityError at /admin/LocalManager/intensivecare_forms/add/

UNIQUE constraint failed: LocalManager_intensivecare_forms.unites_id_id

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/LocalManager/intensivecare_forms/add/
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

UNIQUE constraint failed: LocalManager_intensivecare_forms.unites_id_id

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.9.6
```

Comment: It looks like you turned the `unites_id` from a `OneToOneField` into a `ForeignKey`, but did not (completely) migrate the database through that migration.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. Write as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unites_id` was a `OneToOneField` initially. A `OneToOneField` is basically a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, such that two `intensivecare_forms` can not point to the same `unites`.

Later you turned it into a `ForeignKey`, but forgot to migrate the database, so the `UNIQUE` constraint was still enforced by the database.

By `makemigrations` and `migrate`, normally you can drop the `UNIQUE` constraint, and thus let two `intensivecare_forms` point to the *same* `unites`.